# issue with ffmpeg split mp3 file into ts file(s)

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, http-live-streaming

So I'm trying to split the mp3 file I have into .ts files using ffmpeg. Here's the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp3 o1.ts
```

The test.mp3 is a 28 seconds long audio.
Then I created a m3u8 file, output.m3u8, with the following content:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:30

#EXTINF:28.000,
http://localhost:8000/o1.ts
```

Here's the folder structure
[image: folder structure]

Then from command I started a local http server to serve these files

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

I entered http://localhost:8000/output.m3u8 into the vlc player, but it doesn't play it. So what's the problem with my steps here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to add

```
-acodec mp3
```

as an option for the ffmpeg command, otherwise it somehow defaults to mp2.